# Are all Python3 built-in modules compatible with asyncio? (python 3.7)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7

I thought I read somewhere that not all modules work with asyncio. I can't seem to find the place that I read it. I have a threaded program that uses the socket module heavily and want to try rewriting it with asyncio. I'm also referring to the newest 3.7 version of asyncio (I believe it changed a bit again).

Comment: Please expound on your question as this is very broad as is. You’re asking if all of the several thousand modules included in vanilla python are compatible with asyncio whereas if you say you’re having trouble with one module or one line while converting over to asyncio and include an example with traceback, that would be much easier to answer. That said I believe you should attempt to rewrite it if that’s what you want and come back when you have a question/issue. It’s in the library for a reason and doubt it would be if there were bugs or conflictions with at least complimentary libraries.

Comment: No, for example `sleep()` built-in delay method is not awaitable, and there is an awaitable alternative for that: `asyncio.sleep()`

Comment: It is still true that "not all" modules work with asyncio - for example, `urllib`, `imaplib` or `http.server` don't work with asyncio, and likely never will. Asyncio requires a different architecture (async code based on the event loop from the ground up), and it has [its own ecosystem](https://pypi.org/search/?q=&o=&c=Framework+%3A%3A+AsyncIO) of packages that use it. The question you need to ask is not "do all built-in modules work with asyncio", but "are there well-maintained asyncio-based packages that cover the needs of the program I'm writing?"

Comment: Ah okay... that seemed to be "implied" by the tutorials. One mentioned that urllib was not asyncronous and therefore should not be used with asyncio. I guess I'm confused because I tried using the requests library with several coroutines (for experimentation) and it ran.. and it ran FAST... compared to the normal version. I am just not sure if this is bad practice or not